# JQuery Search / Filter listview bad Performance - manually trigger search

Tags: jquery, performance, listview, jquery-mobile

I have implemented a JQuery listview and enabled the search within this list:

```
<ul class="poi-list" id="poi-list" data-enhance="false" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-role="listview" data-filter-placeholder="Search" >
<li data-role=list-divider>
    City One
</li>
<li data-filtertext="City One Entry1 Category" class="textRow">
    <font style="white-space:normal; font-weight: bold; font-size: medium;"> Entry1
        <br>
    </font>
    <font style="white-space:normal; font-size: small; font-weight: normal; color: #838787;"> Category </font>
</li>
<li data-role=list-divider>
    City Two
</li>
<li data-filtertext="City Two Entry1 Category" class="textRow">
    <font style="white-space:normal; font-weight: bold; font-size: medium;"> Entry1
        <br>
    </font>
    <font style="white-space:normal; font-size: small; font-weight: normal; color: #838787;"> Category </font>
</li>
...
```

The input field is provided by jquery automatically due to the data-filter attribute:

```
<input placeholder="Search" data-type="search" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c">
```

Unfortunately the performance on mobile devices - especially the older ones - is very very bad. There are about 300 Entries in the list and the keyboard input of the mobile device is lagging hard.

I would like to prevent this obvious lagging by adding a button and only start the search when the user tabbed this button. Atm the search is instantly, which means on every keyboard event.

Is there any way to achieve this or improve performance?

Comment: Could you show the code where the user inputs the search? All we see now is a list. Also you should use `span` instead of `font`, because it's not supported since HTML5: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/font

Comment: @Broxzier The search input field is provieded by jquery and I've not customized the search. I added the input field which is responsible for the filtering. Thanks, I'll try span instead of font

Comment: @Broxzier Using span instead of font did not change the performance issue